# IIS 7.5 FTP Service User UserGroups for Authorisation

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp, iis-7.5, windows

i have a W2K8 R2 with the IIS FTP Service and a local windows user group (ftpusers).
In addition to this i have several Windows Accounts, which all only belong to the ftpusers group.

The FTP Server is configured to allow the ftpusers to access the server (with isolated root for each user).

Whenever i add an user to the ftpusers groups the ftp server does not recognize, that the user is allowed to use the site.
I have to do a iisreset to force the ftpserver to reload the user database.

now my Question:
Is there any way to force the ftpserver to update the user/roles without restarting the whole iis, as there are also running several websites on this machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do so, simply by restarting the `FTP Publishing Service` from the Services console (`services.msc`), or with `sc`

Comment: Thank you. I Thought, the FTP Service would be running inside the IIS process.